How do I install dpkg onto a linux distro that has no package manager?
I'm buildning a minimalistic Linux OS for my tiny embedded board. The specifications of the board is 650 MHz CPU, 512 MB Ram and 8 GB HDD.
Totay I'm running a very basic Linux OS that have only the absolutely basic commands + ssh for connection. My goal is to build a very empty Linux with support of Ubunut packages.
I want to install dpkg on that computer. The processor is armhf e.g Cortex A7 or armv7l. So how can that be done?
I have found the source of the dpkg, but I don't know if that's the right way to go.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/1.22.6ubuntu6
The best way is to find the compiled binaries for armhf. I haven't found a way to download.

Download the dpkg package manually from packages.ubuntu.com. Open the downloaded package (it's an ar archive). Locate the compiled binary and config files within the package. Place those files appropriately onto your system.

@user535733 Thank you, but the package is not available to download. https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/armhf/dpkg/download

For armhf, try http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/d/dpkg/

@user535733 Thank you. It's working. But...it takes a LOT of time to download all .deb and extract them and copy them into the folders!!! Is there any simplier way to do this? Like a shell script that install the package manager?

Only if you write it.

@user535733 Thank you
